# Does smartgwt-skins.jar have to be on server?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm trying to trim excess cruft from the .war file for my GWT / SmartGWT web application.  Does smartgwt-skins.jar have to be in the .war file?  IOW, does it provide anything used by the server?  Or does it just need to be on my classpath so the GWT compiler can find it when building the client?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need it on the server.  The same goes for smartgwt.jar.

If you are using the Pro or other paid versions and SmartGWT server-side features then you will need some of the isomorphic-*.jar files on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it only needs to be in your classpath for the GWT compiler can find it when building the client.

It really depends on coding practice. If you have inadvertently used some Client side constants or code from smartgwt-skins.jar in your server side code you need to have it in your WAR's WEB-INF/lib.